# How do I feed shrubs sitting in mulch?

Tags: fertilizer, shrubs, mulch

My flower beds have landscaping fabric covering them, with 2-3 inch depth of mulch sitting on top.

Are there any ways to feed my plants that don't require me to remove the fabric and mulch? Up until now, all I have done is water them.

Comment: All of the plants are Trees and permanent shrubs and the soil was not enriched when I planted them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you've got growing in the beds, whether they're permanent shrubs/trees or just herbaceous perennials, also whether or not the soil was enriched before planting. Most plants do perfectly well without any chemical feeds being applied if the soil is in healthy condition. That said, you could use diluted fertiliser and water it on at the base of the plants, making sure you get it onto soil and not the membrane, if you can see something suffering particularly. Alternatively, ssuming your landscape fabric is porous membrane, you could use a granular fertiliser such as growmore; though it wouldn't look that attractive scattered over the mulch, particularly if its bark chips, it would eventually dissolve and wash down through the membrane.